# How to get click event in android direct share

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-share

I've implemented **Direct Share** in my android app. Its working fine but the problem is I want to get click event means if I click on facebook then how will I know that facebook was clicked. Because I want to implement **ShareLinkContent** when the user clicks on Facebook. This is what I'm doing for direct share :

```
public static void directShare(Activity activity, String shareText) {
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder
                .from(activity)
                .setType("text/plain")
                .setText(shareText)
                .createChooserIntent();
        if (shareIntent.resolveActivity(
                activity.getPackageManager()) != null)
            activity.startActivity(shareIntent);

    }
```

**DirectShareService class**

```
public class DirectShareService extends ChooserTargetService {

    @Override
    public List<ChooserTarget> onGetChooserTargets(ComponentName targetActivityName,
                                                   IntentFilter matchedFilter) {
        ArrayList<ChooserTarget> targets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            DirectShareModel contact = DirectShareModel.byId(i);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putInt(DirectShareModel.ID, i);
            targets.add(new ChooserTarget(
                    // The name of this target.
                    contact.getName(),
                    // The icon to represent this target.
                    Icon.createWithResource(this, contact.getIcon()),
                    // The ranking score for this target (0.0-1.0); the system will omit items with
                    // low scores when there are too many Direct Share items.
                    0.5f,
                    // The name of the component to be launched if this target is chosen.
                    null,
                    // The extra values here will be merged into the Intent when this target is
                    // chosen.
                    extras));
        }
        return targets;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with "direct share". "Direct share" is what is supplying that first row of icons in your screenshot. None of those are Facebook.

On Android 5.1+, you are welcome to use [the three-parameter form of `createChooser()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser(android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender)) to find out what the user chooses. "Because I want to implement ShareLinkContent when the user clicks on Facebook" -- AFAIK that is not possible; the user will go to the Facebook app directly.

Comment: @CommonsWare can u share an example of three-parameter form of createChooser() ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have an example of that.